# Can Google Analytics symbolicate iOS crash reports?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I couldn't find any evidence online that Google Analytics can symbolicate iOS crash reports. I'm using the GA SDK 3.0.

Comment: Any ideas about that?

Comment: @mllm I think it doesn't do that.